# Laravel Nova show 2 CRUD tables in 1 Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible to show two tables with CRUD operations from different models in a single Resource? As I see now, a single Resource is related to 1 model, so I'm thinking of a custom resource. Where can I find an implementation description of such kind functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and a bit easy

1. First you have to install this package:
   https://novapackages.com/packages/DigitalCloud/nova-custom-views
   (please note that this package is not fully compatible with the latest version of laravel and will generate some errors but you can solve it as indicated right here: https://github.com/DigitalCloud/nova-custom-views/issues/24#issuecomment-618350721)
2. create 3 resources, lets call them MainResource, SubResource1, SubResource2..
   MainResource will server as the dual index container, SubResource1 and SubResource2 will server as the sub tables for your models
3. Then you need to create a custom index view of the MainResource using the nova-custom-views commands
4. modify the index view to look like this:

   ```
   <index-view 
   resourceName="subresource1"
   />

   <index-view 
   resourceName="subresource2"
   />
   ```